# Java. LLamar un metodo que devuelve array y mostrarlo sin que aparezca la direccion de memoria

Tags: java, método

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo mostrar desde mi main, un método que me esta devolviendo un array sin que me devuelve una direccion de memoria?.
Mi código ahora mismo esta así.

```
Main

System.out.println(ciudad1.getMaximas());
//Aqui quiero que me imprima lo que contiene el array, pero sale la direccion de memoria.

Clase
float []getMaximas(){
return temperaturaMaxima;     
}
```

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que adjuntaras todo tu codigo al momento de realizar una pregunta, asi sera mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Te refieres a mostrar el contenido del array?

Comment: Si solucionaste tu problema con las respuestas, deberías aceptar la respuesta que te ayudó. También puedes votar para respuestas que eran útiles para ti. No es necesario de dar las gracias a todos en los comentarios, el agradecimiento se subentiende con los votos.

Answer (score 5):

Los arrays son objetos que heredan la implementación de `toString()` de Object (que es esa cadena rara con números -no necesariamente una posición de memoria-).

No se puede reimplementar el método `toString()` de un array, así que hay dos opciones:

- Iterar sobre el array (por ejemplo con un `enhanced for`) e imprimir cada item del array por separado.
- Usar el método `toString(Object[])` de `java.util.Arrays`, que hace más o menos lo mismo.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, voy a iterarlo para que me imprima cada posición del array.

Answer (score 2):

Hola lo puedes hacer importando la Clase java.util.Arrays;

y reemplazando tu codigo :

System.out.println(ciudad1.getMaximas());

por lo siguiente

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ciudad1.getMaximas()));

Espero te sirva

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Un arreglo es un objeto, y lo que se te muestra no es una dirección de memoria, pero simplemente un nombre asignado al objeto. Lo que tienes que hacer es iterar sobre el arreglo para mostrarlo:

```
float[] temperaturaMaxima = { 22.488L, 32.433L, 27.32L  };

public float[] getMaxima(){
    return temparaturaMaxima;
}

public String arregloToJSONString(float[] arreglo){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i<arreglo.length; i++ ){
        sb.append(String.valueOf(arreglo[i]));
        if (i<arreglo.length-1) sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(" ]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

El código te da una representación del arreglo en este caso en formato JSON, pero en el fondo tu eliges como presentar tus datos.

```
System.out.println(arregloToJSONString(getMaxima()));
// => "[ 22.488, 32.433, 27.32 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Un loop? que tal...

```
System.out.println("Array:");
for(Float numero: ciudad1.getMaximas())
    System.out.println("-- "+numero);
```

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza un método toString. Creo que los arrays de java por defecto tiene uno definido. Si no, puedes sobrescribir el propio método para que devuelva una cadena con el formato que tu quieras.

Comment: No puedes reimplementar el método `toString()` de un array.

Comment: Tienes razón, disculpa, queria decir, definir tu mismo un metodo con la funcionalidad de toString().